# Iframe content disappears in Chrome after iframe injection

Tags: google-chrome, iframe

Every time I load the page, parent version of javascript checks if some info has to be inserted into iframe (redrawing objects with [Raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/)) and if it has, it does.

Works fine in IE8, IE9 but crashes in Chrome - iframe's content disappears after parent page tries to make an injection (calling a function inside of an iframe).

No errors whatsoever.

Chrome version: 23.0.1271.97

Comment: The parent page and iframe page is from same domain?

Comment: Yes, same domain, even the same application folder.